# How to retrieve cookie from response retrofit, okhttp?

Tags: android, cookies, retrofit2, session-cookies, okhttp

I am trying to retrieve Cookies values from API response for maintaining the backend session by setting cookie value to new API call in case the APP is closed :

The response to API call from **PostMan RestClient**:
[image]

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {

    if (checkClient()) {
        return getRetrofit();
    }

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieManager();

    okhttp3.OkHttpClient client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
            .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
```

**API Call**

```
private void userLogin(String username, String password) {
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getClient();

    final LoginServices loginServices = retrofit.create(LoginServices.class);
    Call<LoginResponse> call = loginServices.userLogin(username, password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            Log.d("Response code:", "===========" + response.code());

            Log.d("==Cookie==1===", "==="+response.raw().request().headers().get("Cookie"));
            Log.d("==Cookie==2==", "==="+response.headers().get("Cookie"));
            Log.d("==Content-Type====", "==="+response.headers().get("Content-Type"));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("TAG", "=======onFailure: " + t.toString());
            t.printStackTrace();
            // Log error here since request failed
        }
    });
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
Response code:: ===========200
==Cookie==1===: ===null
==Cookie==1===: ===null
==Content-Type====: ===application/json
```

I also tried other various methods they didn't worked for me. Please Help!

Comment: response.raw().headers().get("Cookie") try this

Comment: already tried, not working @ManthanPatel

Comment: @AnuragDhunna, refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nikhiljha/52d45ca69a8415c6990d2a63f61184ff).

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes doesn't work :(

Answer (score 19):

```java
List<String> Cookielist = response.headers().values("Set-Cookie");
String jsessionid = (Cookielist .get(0).split(";"))[0];
```

This worked for me, not the perfect solution,but it worked

Comment: In my case I need to do the following to get it. List<String> Cookielist = response.headers().values("Set-Cookie"); String jsessionid = (Cookielist.get(0).split(";"))[0].split("=")[1];

Answer (score 15):

Header name is "Set-Cookie" not "Cookie" and by the way

The approach you are taking It not proper. If you want to save the Cookie, you can create an interceptor and save the Cookie and use later whenever you want to use.

Here what you have to do, First create an interceptor

```
public class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;

public ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(Context context) {
    FineractApplication.get(context).getComponent().inject(this);
    preferencesHelper = PreferencesHelper(context)
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());

    if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
        HashSet<String> cookies = new HashSet<>();
        for (String header : originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
            cookies.add(header);
        }
        // Save the cookies (I saved in SharedPrefrence), you save whereever you want to save
        preferencesHelper.putStringSet(PreferenceKey.PREF_KEY_COOKIES, cookies);
    }
    return originalResponse;
  }
}
```

Here we are saving all the cookies that you are getting in response.

Now You have cookies it's time to use it.

Wherever you want to use it, just get the cookies that you saved earlier

```
 HashSet<String> cookies = (HashSet<String>) preferencesHelper.getStringSet(
                        PreferenceKey.PREF_KEY_COOKIES);
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (String cookie: cookies) {  
                // Use this cookie whereever you wanna use.               
                Log.d("Cookie", cookie);                 
            }
        }
```

Best of luck

Comment: Hi i followed this from Gist https://gist.github.com/nikhiljha/52d45ca69a8415c6990d2a63f61184ff Do I have to call AddCookieInterceptor and ReceiveCookieInterceptor every time I have query to the server? Example: I have login query what Interceptor will I use? Then I have second query like get some data, what Interceptor will i use? Please reply. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try `response.headers().get("Set-Cookie"))`

Comment: this is not entirely correct. to get all cookies using response.headers().values("Set-Cookie")) which returns a List<String> and should have all your cookies

Answer (score 0):

I have recently switched to a much simpler way to receive and send cookies with `OkHttp` and `Retrofit`, using the [`CookieJar`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cookie-jar/) interface.

First, create a class and implement the `CookieJar` interface and its functions. In this class, you can receive and send cookies.

```
import okhttp3.Cookie
import okhttp3.CookieJar
import okhttp3.HttpUrl

class MyCookieJar : CookieJar {

    val cookieStorage = CookieDataStore()

    override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookies: List<Cookie>) {
        cookieStorage.storeCookies(cookies)
    }

    override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie> {
        return cookieStorage.getCookies()
    }

}
```

Then introduce `MyCookieJar` to your `OkHttpClient`:

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cookieJar(MyCookieJar())
        .build()
```